# SQL Query with 4 Tables but showing multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

Apologies for my basic question, my minds gone blank and for some reason I can't think for the life of me what I've done.

Ok, so I have four tables

1. `dbo.loanunits` (this contains all loan units including status of in or out and loanid)
2. `dbo.loanunits2` (this contains extra info on loan units including customer id and loanid)
3. `dbo.loantrans` (this contains transactions of loanunits, i.e. history of statuses in's and outs. also includes loanid of item sent out)
4. `dbo.customers` (this contains customer id and customer name)

This is my script:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.loanunits.loan_id, dbo.loanunits.loan_name, 
    dbo._loanunits.loan_status, dbo.customers.customername
FROM         
    dbo.loanunits 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.loantrans ON dbo.loanunits.loan_id = dbo.loantrans.loan_tranunitid 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.loanunits2 ON dbo.loantrans.loan_id = dbo.loanunits2.loan_id   
INNER JOIN
    dbo.customers ON dbo.loanunits2.customer_account_code = dbo.customers.customer_account_code
WHERE     
    (dbo.loanunits.loan_status = 'out')
```

I am currently getting the number of results in the transactions table but I should be getting only unique values in the loan units as I only want to see loan units out with customers and who they are with.

Comment: I think you just need to throw a `GROUP BY` at the end and it call it a day. I'm a little confused why you have to join `loantrans` in at all. Is that really the only way to get from `loanunits` to `loanunits2`?

Comment: unfortunately yes, I wish there was another way! :(

Comment: Darn... In any case, put `GROUP BY dbo.loanunits.loan_id, dbo.loanunits.loan_name, dbo._loanunits.loan_status, dbo.customers.customername` at the end and you should get distinct records out of the query.

Comment: You can use "Distinct" after select

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any use of loantrans table, so you may remove it.

```
SELECT     
    dbo.loanunits.loan_id, dbo.loanunits.loan_name, 
    dbo._loanunits.loan_status, dbo.customers.customername
FROM         
    dbo.loanunits 
/*INNER JOIN
    dbo.loantrans ON dbo.loanunits.loan_id = dbo.loantrans.loan_tranunitid */
INNER JOIN
/*    dbo.loanunits2 ON dbo.loantrans.loan_id = dbo.loanunits2.loan_id   */
    dbo.loanunits2 ON dbo.loanunits.loan_id = dbo.loanunits2.loan_id   
INNER JOIN
    dbo.customers ON dbo.loanunits2.customer_account_code = dbo.customers.customer_account_code
WHERE     
    (dbo.loanunits.loan_status = 'out')
```

Also, you could easily use the `DISTINCT` keyword.